# Why can a differential backup not be copy-only?

Tags: sql-server, backup

I have noticed that copy only backups does not allow for differential backups.
What is the reason the copy-only backup option is disabled for differential backups?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It can be specified in TSQL but [the documentation states](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms191495.aspx)

> `COPY_ONLY` has no effect when specified with the `DIFFERENTIAL` option.

There's no need for copy only differential backups because you can just take a normal differential backup.

Taking a differential backup doesn't break anything as each such backup is cumulative and contains all changes since the last *full* backup.

If you were to take a full backup without `copy_only` that would potentially be problematic as it resets the differential base (clears the bitmaps containing information about which extents have changed).

Comment: It is a bit unexpected (to me anyway) that a differential can't be applied to a copy only backup. On the face of it, I would have thought differential with copy only could be useful in some scenarios.